# Finding a printable character not contained in a given character set

Tags: java, regex, character

I want to write a library to generate a String from a given regex. However, I run into a problem, if the regex uses a negated character class, like `[^a-z]`. In this case, I have to place a character into the generated String that does not match `[a-z]`. Also, I want to be able to define a set of characters that are used preferably, e.g. the set of printable characters.

**Question**

How do I generate a random character that is not contained in a given array/collection? How can I prefer groups of characters in this process?

An existing function in the libraries would be great, however I wasn't able to find one.

Here is my approach to solve the problem, however I wonder if there is a better algorithm. Also, my algorithm does not prefer a given set of characters, mainly because I do not know how to check if a character is printable or how I get an array/collection/iterable of printable characters.

```
private void run() {
    int i = 1024;
    System.out.println(getFirstLegalChar(createExampleIllegalCharArray(i)));
    System.out.println((char) i);
}

private char getFirstLegalChar(char[] illegalCharArray) {
    for (int i = 0; true; i++) {
        if (!contains(illegalCharArray, (char) i)) {
            return (char) i;
        }
    }
}

private char[] createExampleIllegalCharArray(int size) {
    char[] illegalCharArray = new char[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < illegalCharArray.length; i++) {
        illegalCharArray[i] = (char) i;
    }
    return illegalCharArray;
}

private boolean contains(char[] charArray, char c) {
    for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
        if (charArray[j] == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you can check the list of printable and non printable characters at http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/idp5.1/topics/reference/general/intrusion-detection-prevention-custom-attack-object-extended-ascii.html

Comment: I found, that [there are non printable unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters). A Java method to list the printable characters would be great.

Comment: i don't think java library has such method. you can design yours.

Comment: I guess you are right, make that an answer and it will be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the list of printable and non printable characters at 
[Juniper](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/idp5.1/topics/reference/general/intrusion-detection-prevention-custom-attack-object-extended-ascii.html).

i have checked few things and come-up with one solution you can check

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
           final char RECORD_SEPARATOR = 0x1e;
             final char END_OF_TEXT = 0x03;
             System.out.println(isPrintableChar(RECORD_SEPARATOR));
             System.out.println(isPrintableChar(END_OF_TEXT));
             System.out.println(isPrintableChar('a'));
          }
    public static boolean isPrintableChar( char c ) {
        Character.UnicodeBlock block = Character.UnicodeBlock.of( c );
        return (!Character.isISOControl(c)) &&
                c != KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED &&
                block != null &&
                block != Character.UnicodeBlock.SPECIALS;
    }
```

i got the output as

```
false
false
true
```